# node js process name on windows

Tags: node.js, webstorm

I'm new to Node.js

I created a node js sample project on WebStorm11 using the "Node.js Express App" template.
I added an html file and just opened it on browser and it worked.

My question is how I know what process on Windows is managing the requests to my application? I want to stop it through Task Manager.

Besides, I tried to stop the process by typing ctrl+c in command line and it didn't work. Any suggestions why?

Any help will be profoundly appreciated!

Comment: isn't it `node.exe`?

Comment: node.exe should be the one. if ctrl+c doesn't work you can probably just close the command line terminal.

Comment: I don't see a process that's called node.js unfortunately. I didn't turn on the server from the terminal, and the terminal is actually closed now but I still can see this page on browser. Maybe WebStorm uses a different process? I also tried closing WebStorm and restart my computer and it didn't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems you didn't run your Express application, did you? Opening HTML file in browser, well, just opens it on WebStorm default built-in webserver, it doesn't start your Express server. Please see https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/WI/Running+and+debugging+Node.js+application for instructions on running Node.js applications in WebStorm

Comment: Thanks a lot Elena! Now it makes sense!